# Filtering Memory messages in logcat

Tags: android, shell, grep, adb

Will my windows-7, command prompt allow me to filter memory logcat messages for my application.

If this is possible,how do i filter messages.

I tried this adb shell logcat | grep pid > "path to output file"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote the code to print log messages, you have the log tag, which you can grep for.

For instance,

```
private static final String TAG = "applog";
....
{
    Log.e(TAG, "this is a log");
}
```

To see these messages, type `adb logcat | grep 'applog'`
Also, if you have multiple different log tags, you can use the command `adb logcat | grep 'tagone\|tagtwo'`

Hope that helps!

Comment: :Can you upvote my question,What is memory specific messages that will be present in logcat.

Comment: @casperOne:I marked it to admin review,this is real question,i've not got real answer to it.